# POST JavaScript array as data

Tags: javascript, json

A quick question. I need to submit an array of object to the server as POST, but not an ajax request. I build the data through javascript, and not part of a form. I could think about an option, by creating a mock form with a submit button, and send the data as json. IS there a better way. Is there a native jQuery JSON encoder available? or is there a better way. I see serialize interface, but it may be difficult parse the string at the server, JSON is easier.

thanks,

bsr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify(arrayObject)` to convert the array to JSON.

Another alternative, if you're building a mock form anyway, is to build your array using a number of `<input type="hidden"/>` fields with the same name.

Comment: Yup -- this is the approach I would go with, and then you should be able to json_decode it php side

Comment: thanks .. I didn't know that latest browsers has native JSON support.. http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-native-json.html http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=470

Answer (score 0):

An "ajax request" **IS**, in almost all implementations you are likely to encounter, a POST (or GET) request.